# Open Modal after navigation step done

Tags: javascript, angular, modal-dialog

Simple navigation step which i need to wait til done, in order for the modal to have it's template on the page we are navigating to.

```
public onOpenModal(item) {
  this.router.navigate([item.link]).then(() => {
    this.modal.open('createSpace'); // Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Modal not found
  });
  this.modal.open('createSpace'); // works fine
}
```

for some reason when I cal this.modal.open() inside the then() block it errors out. I'm suspecting a scope issue? Any ideas? if I call modal.open() outside the then() block it works, however I need to wait for the navigation jump is complete.

EDIT: I believe the template hasn't fully loaded... maybe that's why Modal can't be found... would make sense.

Is there a way to truly wait for the template to be ready?

Comment: Please specify what `this.modal` is in this context.

Comment: @SiddAjmera this.modal opens an API to manipulate a modal defined by a templ identifier in this case #createSpace. I think the issue is that the tpl is not ready yet, so the identifier isn't loaded. Is there a way to truly wait for the tpl to be FULLY loaded before running the modal code?

Comment: [Don't assume a solution if you don't know the issue](http://xyproblem.info/). Also, please post more context to the question, such as a [mcve] or the full code of your component.

Answer (score 0):

This is strange. Not really sure why is this an issue in the first place. But would you please try doing this and see if it works:

```
async onOpenModal(item) {
  await this.router.navigate([item.link]);
  this.modal.open('createSpace');
}
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/open-modal-after-navigation-is-complete?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhome%2Fhome.component.ts) for your ref.

---

**NOTE:** You didn't really specify what this modal was, so I used ngx-bootstrap modal in the example. But should work as expected in your case as well.

Comment: I tried it with async await and also with NavigationEnd... It's weird. I'm 99% sure the template isn't ready yet, but I don't see why.

Comment: It would be great and really helpful if you could create a minimal sample stackblitz replicating this issue.